# Plural "They" or "It"

Tags: usage, pronouns

I have read an article about **Plural They** and now I have a question struggling in my mind.
Consider the following sentences:

> Each child played with ***their*** parent.
>
> Every client got a care package delivered to ***them***.

May I use the pronoun "it" or "it's" in place of "they" or "theirs" like the following ones?

> Each child played with ***it's*** parent.
>
> Every client got a care package delivered to ***it***.

If it's possible, Isn't it uncommon or odd, somehow?

Comment: *Its* doesn't work because we don't use *it* to refer to humans (even to the little ones)

Comment: "We recognise that **each child has its own starting point** upon entry to every year group and progress is measured in line with these starting points to ensure every child can celebrate success." - Coley Primary School, Reading, Berkshire, UK. "Each child **has its own cot or bed** for sleep time" - City Limits Child Care, Hamilton, New Zealand.

Comment: There is no apostrophe in _**its** parent_, which is correct in British usage, but slightly old-fashioned (some people don't like to refer to children as 'it' nowadays). –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English has *personal* and *non-personal* pronouns.

*It* is a non-personal pronoun and sounds dehumanizing when you use it to refer to something that's a person.  *It* is used for objects and animals that aren't pets.

> Each child played with their parent.

This is what you want to say for this sentence.

> Every client got a care package delivered to it.

This would be OK if the client is not a person--for example, if it's a company and you're talking about delivering packages to their front desk to give to the rest of the company.

> Every client got a care package delivered to them.

So this is awkward because *them* refers to a group of things but *every client* refers to each individual X in a group of things.  You should reword the sentence this way:

> A care package was delivered to every client.

Comment: This is advice about being 'human', not grammar.

Comment: I do not understand the above comment or the downvote.

Comment: Is this true about the pronoun **that**?

Comment: Yes.  *That* is a *demonstrative* pronoun, but not a personal pronoun.